# Pass a dynamic variable into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the value which I am getting from an AJAX call to an array I provide to `countrySelect()`;

I want the `cc` variable in the following example to be passed in this array:

```
preferredCountries: ['pk','gb', 'us']
```

I tried this but it does not work for me.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "callback",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(location) {
    var cc = location.country_code;
    var ncc = cc.toLowerCase();
  }
});

$("#country_selector").countrySelect({
  preferredCountries: ['pk', 'gb', 'us']
});
```

Comment: To do this you will need to call `countrySelect()` *after* the AJAX call has completed

Comment: Are you trying to *add* a record to the "country select*?  Or select an existing record?  Something else?  What documentation does this plugin provide for doing what you're trying to do?

Comment: can you please give as an example.

Comment: and why on earth would you want to call a lowercase country code `lastname`

Comment: actually i am creating a auto select country filed with country flag according to geo location, for exmple some one online from UK so this script select uk option automatically.

Comment: because upper case letter not working with the bellow code so therefore i need to convert and then push this to array of countrySelect() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your code to synchronize after you get the response.

```
var getGeoData = function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: "callback",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: callback
    });
};


// Call the getGeoData function with callback
getGeoData(function (location) {
    var cc = location.country_code;
    var ncc = cc.toLowerCase();

    sessionStorage.setItem('lastname', ncc);
    $('#country_selector').attr('selected', true);
    
    const countrySelectConfig = {
        preferredCountries: ['pk', 'gb', 'us']
    };
    countrySelectConfig.preferredCountries.push(cc);
    $("#country_selector").countrySelect(countrySelectConfig);
});
```

Comment: @Arslanminko what was the issue earlier ?

Comment: @ Kunal Mukherjee its worked thank you soo much again

Comment: i was unable to pass value to array